# Recommendations for Stock Trading and Investment Applications?

Tags: software-recommendation

I am looking for a good in-depth stocks or investment application. I have tried GRISM but it is lacking. There are others Ive found like JStock which uses java, Eclipse Trader which is not user friendly. Stock Market Eye looks interesting, but it is pricey. Can anyone recommend anything else out there? Thanks!

Comment: Actually I doubt that there is a decent stock trading application available for Linux. I recommend you VMWare/VirtualBox with MetaTrader or something.

Comment: You may get more answers if you add a typical use-case to your question.

Comment: whats wrong in JStock?

Answer (score 2):

Try JStock.

JStock makes it easy to track your stock investment. It provides well organized stock market information, to help you decide your best investment strategy.<sup>JStoc</sup>.

To download, and for more information, visit their [website](http://www.jstock.org/)

Comment: For additional information, JStock works well too in Android platform : https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.yccheok.jstock.gui (Disclaim : I'm the author)

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for technical analysis software, then QTStalker is a good native application.  Amibroker runs well under the current versions of Wine and Crossover.

Answer (score 1):

A search using `apt-cache search stock` shows:

- Tryton Application Platform has a Stock Module
- `smtm` or "Show Me The Money" is a configurable Perl/Tk stock ticker program
- If you are into KDE/Plasma you can use `plasma-widget-stockquote` plasma widget which displays stock quotes
- `pandorafms-agent` - Pandora FMS is a Flexible Monitoring System which works as agent
- For perl developers there is the `libfinance-quote-perl`, `libfinance-yahooquote-perl` and `libfinance-histquote-perl`
- `beancounter` A stock portfolio performance monitoring tool

Answer (score 0):

TDAmeritrade's Trade Architect runs through a web browser so you do not have to install anything. I would expect it to utilize some hefty processor time if you want the real-time bells and whistles.

You will need to open an account (with minimal funding) to use their platforms, but you can use them purely for research as opposed to active trading.